# Finding an angle using angular velocity read from a gyro

Tags: integration

I'm making a self-stabilizing camera mount for a Digital Systems project using Arduino. I plan to read angular position from a gyrospcope and adjust servos on the mount accordingly to keep it level.

I've found that the gyro I'm using only reads angular velocity. I've only taken Calc 1, which was three semesters ago now, so my calc is really shaky. I figure that I should be able to integrate to get from the angular velocity I'm given to an angle.

Since all I can read is an angular velocity at any given instant, there isn't a formula or specific set of bounds I can use to integrate.

Is this possible and how would it work?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the APIs which do this?  It turns out that, due to errors that cause drift, this is a bit more difficult than it seems at first.  It's a very common thing to do, so you should be able to use a library.  If not, I'd start by reading about Kalman filters.  They're the first step on the path to being able to make such a device work.

Comment: To be honest, put this project on hold until your calc/math skills are at a level where that drunk txt math app wouldn't be able to stop you.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add the values as they come in. When integrating discrete values that are sampled, you essentially just add them up over time and divide by the sample interval. So keep a running total and add the next reading you get when it comes in. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278784/integrate-readings-from-a-3-axis-gyroscope) for an example of how it works.

However, as @Cort Ammon noted in the comments, you will find this is very noisy and quickly drifts from where you would expect it to be. I second his recommendation to look into Kalman filters and to read up on sensor fusion techniques.

Comment: You also need to divide by the sample interval.

Comment: Fair point! I added a link showing an example.